Global Mapper Scripting Problem Elevation Grid
I have a problem with trying to use a Global Mapper Script in order to create an elevation grid out of lidar data. The final output should be a nCHM exported as an ASCII file.
I narrowed the problem down to:
The script does in fact create an elevation grid but only uses default parameters and not the specified ones I give it. It just ignores it. Except for the layer name.
First it just took ages to triangulate the ground until I set the "SET_OPT LIDAR_FILTER=None,2" in front of it. Thats how I know it ignores the specified parameters as the "LIDAR_FILTER=none,2" is already in the "GENERATE_ELEV_GRID" command.
Here is the code I use:
`GLOBAL_MAPPER_SCRIPT VERSION="1.00"
// Start looping through .laz files in the directory where the script is located
DIR_LOOP_START DIRECTORY="" FILENAME_MASKS="*.laz"
IMPORT FILENAME="%FNAME_W_DIR%" TYPE="LIDAR_LAS" ELEV_UNITS="METERS" \
     LABEL_FIELD_FORCE_OVERWRITE="NO" LABEL_FORMAT_NUMBERS="YES" \
     LABEL_PRECISION="-1" LABEL_REMOVE_TRAILING_ZEROS="YES" \
     LABEL_USE_SCIENTIFIC_NOTATION="NO" LOAD_FLAGS="535822336" \
     ALT_MODE="ABSOLUTE" LIDAR_DRAW_MODE_GLOBAL="YES" LIDAR_DRAW_MODE="CLASS" \
     LIDAR_POINT_SIZE="0" LIDAR_DRAW_QUALITY="85" LIDAR_BRIGHTNESS="0" \
     BAND_RANGE="ALL,0" CLIP_COLLAR="NONE" PROJ="EPSG:21781"
DEFINE_VAR Name="Data_name" Value=%PARENT_DIR%
DIR_LOOP_END

SET_OPT LIDAR_FILTER=None,2

// Generate elevation grids
GENERATE_ELEV_GRID ELEV_UNITS="METERS" GRID_ALG="TIN" \
GRID_BIN_SIZE="-0.8" LAYER_DESC="Boden" NO_DATA_DIST_MULT="29.486854" \
GRID_SAVE_TIN="NO" GRID_FILL_TO_BOUNDS="NO" GRID_FLATTEN_AREAS="YES" \
GRID_HEIGHTS_RELATIVE="NO" GRID_USE_CONSTRAINTS="YES" GRID_IGNORE_ZERO="NO" \
GRID_TYPE="ELEV" LIDAR_FILTER="NONE,2" LIDAR_RETURN_FILTER="ALL"

SET_OPT LIDAR_FILTER=None,5

GENERATE_ELEV_GRID ELEV_UNITS="METERS" GRID_ALG="BIN_MAX" \
GRID_BIN_SIZE="-0.8" LAYER_DESC="Vegetation" NO_DATA_DIST_MULT="3" \
GRID_SAVE_TIN="NO" GRID_FILL_TO_BOUNDS="NO" GRID_FLATTEN_AREAS="YES" \
GRID_HEIGHTS_RELATIVE="NO" GRID_USE_CONSTRAINTS="YES" GRID_IGNORE_ZERO="NO" \
GRID_TYPE="ELEV" SOFT_EDGE_DIST="2" LIDAR_FILTER="NONE,5" LIDAR_RETURN_FILTER="ALL"

// Combine terrain layers
COMBINE_TERRAIN LAYER1_FILENAME="Vegetation" LAYER2_FILENAME="Boden" \
COMBINE_OP="SUBTRACT_SIGNED" COMPARE_VAL="0" LAYER_DESC="nCHM" \
ELEV_UNITS="METERS" SPATIAL_RES="0.800000,0.800000"

// Export the result with directory name + _nCHM
EXPORT_ELEVATION FILENAME="%Data_name%_nCHM.asc" \
TYPE="ARCASCIIGRID" EXPORT_LAYER="nCHM" ELEV_UNITS="METERS" \ 
SPATIAL_RES="0.80000000,0.80000000" GEN_PRJ_FILE="YES"`

Any help would be really appreciated as I been slamming my head against my desk for 2 days now. :D
I did try all sorts of different formating e.g. writing it in 1 line, differen quotation marks, no quotation marks etc.
When trying it in the GUI it works. I used the "copy script" button when manually generating an elvation grid. All the same results. It just uses the default parameters.
